# Subset data frame bay selecting row data every 16 days in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this huge data set

[image]

and wanted to select the row every 16 days.
I tried with dplyr but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
 df[seq(1, nrow(df), by = 16),]
```

Answer (score 1):

To select every 16th row, you can do:

```r
df[seq(nrow(df)) %% 16 == 1,]
```

This will filter your data frame so it only contains row 1, row 17, row 33, row 49, etc

Answer (score 0):

Or using `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(row_number() %% 16 == 1)
```